# To upgrade two PCs to Windows 10, are separate reservations required?

Tags: windows, windows-10-upgrade, windows-10

I have a reservation on my Windows 8.1 computer, but I also have a Windows 7 laptop. 
Do I need a separate reservation for my laptop to get Windows 10 free?

Comment: Before, probably yes. Now the tool/ISO is released by Microsoft so you can upgrade using that.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [faq](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/Windows-10-faq),you will have to reserve each copy of Windows 10 separately. So you have to press the get windows 10 icon on each computer. yes, you do need a separate reservation.

EDIT:
A reservation isn't needed now, since Windows 10 is released. So just go [to this official website here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) and find your respective tool, whether you're a 32 or 64 bit. It's very simple and will download and install Windows 10 for you.

Comment: Hmmm, I doubt you even need reservations: if the target version is the same (32/64 bit, and so on), then why not [download a single ISO file](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO) to upgrade both machines?

Comment: Reservations were just a marketing thing. They released the ISO.

Comment: Tha is true. editing now @MC10